# Stream's Length property behaviour when CanSeek = false

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, stream

I'm implementing the `Stream` class.  The new class supports reading and writing but not seeking.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueuestream.length.aspx) says this returns the length of the stream.  As it both reading and writing are supported I don't know how long the string will be until all the writing is finished.

Should I throw a `NotSupportedException` for this as with `SetLength` and `Position`?

The documentation doesn't suggest this is the correct behaviour, however, if I do return a value then how should I calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`Stream.Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length.aspx#Anchor_1)

> **NotSupportedException**: A class derived from Stream does not support seeking.

Additionally from the docs for [`Stream.CanSeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canseek(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

> If a class derived from Stream does not support seeking, calls to Length, SetLength, Position, and Seek throw a NotSupportedException.

So I would throw that rather than try to calculate anything, even if you do know the value at the end of the operation.

Comment: Thanks, I need to open my eyes I think!

Comment: Well it's hard to see these things sometimes when you're in the middle of the forest. It's why rubber duck debugging works so well!

Comment: Is that how Bert & Ernie do their debugging?